# Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am creating a WPF on which, i have 2 threads. One is the main, and the other one(called PillTimeOutChecker) check some requirements in the main form. If the requirements meet, a new form through the PilleCheckerThread show up in a new thread. The problem is that i am getting this error: Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' threw an exception in the initialization of the new form.

This is the method in the main thread, that call the PillCheckerThread:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread PillChecker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PillCheckerThread));
        PillChecker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        PillChecker.IsBackground = true;
        PillChecker.Name = "PillTimeOutChecker";
        PillChecker.Start();
    }
```

This is the content of the PillCheckerThread method:

```
 private void PillCheckerThread()
    {
            foreach (DataGridObject item in PillList.Items)
            {
               if(item.DoIt)
               {
                        //Show PillWarning window
                        Thread PillWarningWindow = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                        {
                             PillWarningWindow pl = new PillWarningWindow(item.PillName, item.AlertTime);
                             pl.Show();
                                 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                            }));
                        PillWarningWindow.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                        PillWarningWindow.IsBackground = true;
                        PillWarningWindow.Start();
              }
           }
    }
```

This is the content of the PillWarningWindow:

```
public partial class PillWarningWindow : Window
{
    public PillWarningWindow(string PillName, string CurrentTime)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PillNameLbl.Content = PillName;
        TimeLbl.Content = CurrentTime;
    }

    private void CloseBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the xaml of the PillWarningWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="MedicalReminder.PillWarningWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MedicalReminder"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Height="300" Width="713.414" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True">
<Border BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="20" Background="DarkCyan">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="CloseBtn" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Click="CloseBtn_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Psssttt !! It's time to take your pill: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
        <Label x:Name="PillNameLbl" Content="PillName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="395,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label x:Name="label2" Content="It's exactly " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>
        <Label x:Name="TimeLbl" Content="12:00" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,133,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="17" Width="56"/>
        <Label x:Name="label3" Content="you forgot it ??" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18"/>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

With a breakpoint at the constructor of the PillWarningWindow i found out that the error start at the InitializeComponent method. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can't say why your code won't work. Maybe the inner exception would help to find the problem. But I hardly recommend using rows and columns in your datagrid instead of using the margin to align your controls. That's really bad code.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom thanks for the instructions. I 'll change the margin/align with rows and columns!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access windows propety you should use Dispatchers.

Because of another thread cannot acces window directly. You can use the Dispatcher when you want to run an operation that will be executed on the UI thread.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
  DispatcherPriority.Background,
  new Action(() =>  PillNameLbl.Content = PillName;
    TimeLbl.Content = CurrentTime));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. I am keep getting the same error. I tried to put the InitializeComponent method inside a dispatcher too.. but then i get this error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it  Here is a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ep0qit

Answer (score 0):

If debugger stops at InitializeComponent method, I'd say there is probably something wrong with your XAML code (which despite of being full of bad practices, doesn't seem to be incorrect). Are you sure your controls don't have style resources defined in any other place? I have had the same error before and it was caused by defining styles in a wrong order.

Try to launch your window directly at the application start instead of launching it from another thread, just to test if it's OK. If it works, then the problem is in the thread management.